# Basis for $U + V$ in terms of bases

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $U$ and $V$ be finite dimensional subspaces of W over a field F. Let $B_{U}$ be a basis for $U$, $B_{V}$ be a basis for $V$, and $B_{U \cap V}$ be a basis for $U \cap V$. Here, $B_{U \cap V} \subset B_{U}$ and $B_{U \cap V} \subset B_{V}$. What I need to do is find a basis for $U + V$ in terms of the bases defined above. From observations I think that a basis for $U + V$ is $B_{V} \cup (B_{U} - B_{U \cap V})$. But I am not quite sure how to show this. Also, is it always the case that $B_{V} \cap (B_{U} - B_{U \cap V})$ is empty?

Comment: This will only work if $B_{U\cap V}\subset B_U$. This does not follow from your assumptions.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I've edited the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes your intuition for the basis of $U + V$ is correct!

Since $U \cap V$ is a subspace, what you do is first take the basis for $U \cap V$.  Call this basis at $\mathcal{B}=\{u_1,u_2,...,u_s\}$ and so $\text{dim}(U \cap V)=s$

Note that $\mathcal{B}$ is a basis for $U \cap V$ implies $\mathcal{B}$ is linearly independent in $U$ as well as in $V$

Therefore $\mathcal{B}$ can be extended to a basis of $U$ ,namely, $\{u_1,u_2,...,u_s,v_1,...,v_t\}$

Similarly   $\{u_1,u_2,...,u_s,w_1,...,w_u\}$ is a basis for $V$.

> Exercise: Prove $\{u_1,u_2,...,u_s,v_1,v_2,...,v_t,w_1,w_2,...,w_u\}$ is a basis for $U+V$

Answer (score 0):

Recall that in general

$$\dim (U+V)=\dim U + \dim V - \dim (U\cap V)$$

and that we have

$$B_{U + V}\subseteq B_{V} \cup B_{U}$$

therefore to find a basis for $U + V$,  that is a set of linear independent vectors which spans $U+V$, we need to start from the set $B_{V} \cup B_{U}$ and proceed by elimination.